# Adding a Gradle dependency on AWS SDK for Java v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle

I'd like to add the latest AWS SDK for Java v2 to my project's Gradle dependencies.
In my case I'd like to add a dependency for `software.amazon.awssdk:core`. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html) I need to add these lines to the `dependencies` block:

```
  implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.10.86')
  implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:core'
```

However, this gives me:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find software.amazon.awssdk:core:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

When I make the version number for the core artifact explicit, the build works. But this defeats the point of importing a BOM via the platform directive.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54061391/412834) but as far as I understand Gradle, I am already adding the platform to the `implementation` configuration when I follow the Amazon docs.

Currently I am using Gradle 5.6.3. Any hints on making this work are appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the BOM (Maven's Bill-of-Material) file that you are referencing. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/software/amazon/awssdk/bom/2.10.86/bom-2.10.86.pom, core was likely split into 3 libraries. `aws-core`, `protocol-core`, `sdk-core`

Comment: do you have IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT enabled?

Comment: I haven't heard about IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT before so probably not. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@SGM1 pointed me in the right direction. The following works:

```
implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.10.86') 
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core'
```

Obviously, the import statements need to be changed to `software.amazon.awssdk.(etc)`.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks! you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @molholm Marked as accepted, even though it was SGM1 who came up with it.